# how to read window dialog fields values using python?

Tags: python, api

I try to read values from fields of a window dialog.

In the dialog configuration I have this:

```
#define IDC_SYMBOL                      8011
#define IDC_SHARES                      8012
```

[dialog snapshot picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce8kr.jpg)

this is my simple code tried:

```
import win32gui,win32con

wT="my_dialog"
dlg=win32gui.FindWindow(None,wT)

d1=win32gui.GetDlgItem(dlg, 8011)
d2=win32gui.GetDlgItem(dlg, 8012)

print('d1: ', d1)
print('d2: ', d2)


def dumpWindow(hwnd, wantedText=None, wantedClass=None):
    windows = []
    hwndChild = None
    while True:
        hwndChild = win32gui.FindWindowEx(hwnd, hwndChild, wantedClass, wantedText)
        if hwndChild:
            textName = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwndChild)
            className = win32gui.GetClassName(hwndChild)
            windows.append((hwndChild, textName, className))
        else:
            return windows 


windows = dumpWindow(dlg, wantedText='Symbol')

print(windows)
```

And this is what I get when running it:

```
d1:  1051340
d2:  920324
[(9112016, 'Symbol', 'Static')]
```

How do I read the actual values in those window dialog fields?

I also tried to get the dialog item text:

```
dText=win32gui.GetDlgItemText(dlg, 8011)
print('dText: ', dText)
```

and result is empty while the expected result is 'AAPL' for example, or whatever is there.

```
dText:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
from sys import exit
import win32gui,win32con

wT="my_dialog"
dlg=win32gui.FindWindow(None,wT)

d1=win32gui.GetDlgItem(dlg, 8011) #symbol

def getEditText(hwnd):
     buffer = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(255)
     bufLen = win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, 255, buffer)
     win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, 255, buffer)
     text = buffer[0:bufLen*2] 
     return text 

print ('Symbol: ', str(getEditText(d1),'utf-16'))
```

this script prints the selected symbol:

```
Symbol: ZVZZT
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use [GetDlgItemText](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui__GetDlgItemText_meth.html).

Normally, this function will return the text of a dialog control

Comment: Because when I try getting the text value, I get nothing. ```dText=win32gui.GetDlgItemText(dlg, 8011)
print('dText: ', dText)```

Comment: anyone knows why I am not getting the value of the dialog field?

Comment: Which language you create your window ? Is it in C or C++ ?. Are you sure that control's have correct ID ?